# 'types' can only be used in a .ts file

Tags: typescript

Please take a look at index.js, package.json, and tsconfig.json files.

index.js

```js
function add(a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b;
}

add(3, 'world');
```

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "tsc:watch": "tsc --watch"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
  }
}
```

If I run `yarn run tsc:watch` command, I get the following errors:

```sh
index.js:1:17 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

1 function add(a: number, b: number) {
                  ~~~~~~

index.js:1:28 - error TS8010: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

1 function add(a: number, b: number) {
                             ~~~~~~
Found 2 errors.
```

Could you please help me understand why allowJs and checkJs compiler options are being ignored? My understanding is, these options allow typescript check in js extensions too. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please rename `index.js` to `index.ts` and try again

Comment: @Wex Thanks for your reply. I know renaming to ts extension works fine, but my question is around why allowJs and checkJs compiler options are being ignored.

Comment: `(a: number, b:number)` is not valid in vanilla JavaScript. I think `--allowJs` will ultimately allow you to import those files, even though type information doesn't exist.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Hi John, thanks for your help. I went through the question you linked. I found the following 

"it will do everything that the TypeScript compiler does except type check your code." 

This could be the reason, but I couldn't find anything like that in typescript documentation, but maybe, this is it.

Comment: Hi @Wex, yes, that's not valid vanilla JavaScript. It looks like allowJs only lets you compile, but types such as `:number` are still not allowed which kind of defeats the purpose to an extend. Anyway, thanks again.